# What's the difference between [BITS 32] declaration and BITS 32, if there is any?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've seen assembly sources in the wild that uses `[BITS 32]` directive. I'm using compiler **NASM** and at its man pages, I've seen no reference to the need of the brackets, so I compiled my own source without them (just `BITS 32`), with no errors, and it works.

Is there any difference from using or not the brackets wrapping compilers directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NASM’s directives come in two types:
>   user-level directives and primitive
>   directives. Typically, each directive
>   has a user-level form and a primitive
>   form. In almost all cases, we
>   recommend that users use the
>   user-level forms of the directives,
>   which are implemented as macros which
>   call the primitive forms.
>
> Primitive directives are enclosed in
>   square brackets; user-level directives
>   are not.

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html